# React hooks make the font-Weight bold depending on the weekday

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I learn how to use React hooks, and I am trying to make the font-Weight bold depending on the weekday.
[enter image description here][1]

```js
import React from "react";


const App = () => {


  var today = new Date().getDay();
  console.log("d" + today);


  return (
 <div>   
    <div className="weekday d1">Monday  10:00AM- 9:00PM </div> <br/>
    <div className="weekday d2">Tuesday 10:00AM- 9:00PM </div> <br/>
    <div className="weekday d3">Wednesday  10:00AM- 9:00PM </div> <br/>
    <div className="weekday d4">Thursday 10:00AM- 9:00PM </div> <br/>
    <div className="weekday d5">Friday  10:00AM- 9:00PM </div> <br/>
    <div className="weekday d6">Saturday  10:00AM- 9:00PM </div> <br/>
    <div className="weekday d7">Sunday Closed </div> <br/>
</div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Please provide some code to support your question.

Comment: I am assuming this is a custom hook you are talking about? Could you please provide the code that you have written so that we can help you out from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first get the current week day from the object of new Date() class. Then you apply the conditional className for styling on the current week days with our state.